# Bürmann-Lagrange formula for a function

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

How to prove that, if
$$
w=ze^{aw^m} \quad (m\in\mathbb{N}),
$$
then
$$
w=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{a^n(nm+1)^{n-1}} {n!}z^{nm+1} \; ?
$$

I am aware of the Bürmann-Lagrange inversion formula, that if $z=we^{-aw^m},$ then 
$$
w=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{z^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}
\lim_{z\to0}\frac{d^n e^{a(n+1)z^m}}{dz^n},
$$
But I have difficulty proving that
$$
\lim_{z\to0}\frac{d^n e^{a(n+1)z^m}}{dz^n}=
\begin{cases}
a^k(km+1)^nkm\cdots(n+1),& \text{if } \; 
n=km+1,\\
0, & \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
 $$
There should probably be a better way to establish the expansion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method  for Lagrange inversion  by the Cauchy  Coefficient Formula
applies here, as documented and proved on page $732$, section $A.6$ of
*Analytic  Combinatorics* by  Flajolet  and Sedgewick.  The reader  is
invited to consult the text for additional information. Introducing

$$Q(z) = \sum_{n\ge 1} Q_n z^n$$

with

$$Q(z) = z \exp(a Q(z)^m)$$

we follow the given reference in writing

$$n Q_n = [z^{n-1}] Q'(z) =
\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^n} Q'(z) \; dz.$$

Now with $z = Q(z) \exp(-a Q(z)^m)$ this is

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{|z|=\epsilon}
\frac{1}{Q(z)^n} \exp(a n Q(z)^m) Q'(z) \; dz.$$

Put $Q(z) = w$ to get

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{|w|=\gamma}
\frac{1}{w^n} \exp(a n w^m) \; dw
= [w^{n-1}] \exp(a n w^m).$$

Here we must have $n=pm+1$ with $p\ge 0$ and we obtain

$$[w^{pm}] \exp(a (pm+1) w^m)
= [w^p] \exp(a (pm+1) w)
= \frac{a^p (pm+1)^p}{p!}.$$

We thus have

$$Q_n =  \frac{1}{pm+1}
\frac{a^p (pm+1)^p}{p!} z^{pm+1}$$

or

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
Q(z) = \sum_{p\ge 0}
\frac{a^p (pm+1)^{p-1}}{p!} z^{pm+1}.}$$